# How to import timestamps & durations in HH:MM:SS format from excel in R?

Tags: r, excel, timestamp, posix, epoch

I have an **excel table**that has a **column** that contains **timestamps** in the format `HH:MM:SS`.
However, after reading in the exported **`CSV`** into **R**, the values in the corresponding column `data$timestamp` are interpreted as a <s>huge</s> small number (e.g., `7,06018515869254E-04`.)

How can I get **R** to interpret the numbers as they were meant to?

I've tried the following without any success (yield `NA`):

```
timeTest <- data$timestamp[1] 
print(as.POSIXct((timeTest - 719529)*86400, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC"))
print(as.POSIXct(strptime(timeTest, %Y%m%d %H%M%S")))
```

A hint how to achieve the desired format would be of great help!

---

Here is a sample from the actual `CSV`:

```
0,692210648148148|0,692534722222222|3,24074074074088E-04
```

As I use `|` as separator, I import the data as follows:

```
data <- read.delim(file,header=TRUE,sep="|")
```

Comment: That's not a huge number, it's a small number (although I doubt that you configured your R in a way that it would use `,` as decimal seperator in the console). Show the first few lines of your CSV and how you import it.

Comment: Looks like a 'language setting' problem. You have a csv-file with pipes as separators and commas as decimal separater!

Comment: @hvollmeier: so what's a workaround for this? Find-replace all "," and replace with "."?

Comment: I do not see a column with `HH:MM:SS` format. However, you should read the file with `read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="|", dec=",")`.

Comment: @Roland: The format ''HH:MM:SS'' is in the original excel file and the sample is from the exported CSV. The export is carried out using a simple VB script...

Comment: I would export the data from Excel in the default date/format for R, which is `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` and import the file with the "dec = "," parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="x|y|timestamp
                 0,692210648148148|0,692534722222222|3,24074074074088E-04",
                 sep="|", dec=",", header=TRUE)
library(chron)
DF$timestamp <- times(DF$timestamp)
#          x         y timestamp
#1 0.6922106 0.6925347  00:00:28
```